# Does Storm Trident newValueStream after persistentAggregate maintain partition from groupBy

Tags: java, apache-storm, trident

I am currently trying to scale a trident topology that does some post processing after a groupBy and persistentAggregate, using newValueStream to stream values after the aggregate step. I was wondering if the tuples remained partitioned as they were during the groupBy step, or are they redistributed in some other fashion.

relevant code:

```
.groupBy(new Fields("key"))
.name("GroupBy")
.persistentAggregate(new MemoryMapState.Factory(), new Fields("foo", "bar"), new Aggregator(), new Fields("foobar"))
.newValuesStream()
.name("NewValueStream")
```